# Using substring till the last character replacement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string as follows:

```
var mainstring = "Hello thereworld";
var substring = "there";
```

in the mainstring , the last part is varying all the time like this after "there"

```
var mainstring = "Hello theresometext1";
```

I have a task where I have to replace world with task variable if "there" exists in mainstring

```
var task="new"
```

the final output should be :

```
var mainstring = "Hello therenew";

This is what my expected output is:

if(mainstring.IndexOf(substring)!=-1)
{
 mainstring.replace(substring,substring+task);
}
```

But I am getting the output as:

```
var mainstring = "Hello thereworldnew";
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me yet... "Hello thereworld" should become "Hello therenew" and "Hello theresometext1" should become WHAT??

Comment: "Hello theresometext1" should be "Hello therenew" itself because var task = "new" here as well .Basically whatever string comes after "there" should be deleted and replaced with var task;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `replace` returns the modified string: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

So you have to assign the result of the `replace` function to `mainstring` again.

And you say: "I have to replace world with task", but where in your code do you replace world? `string.replace(search, replaceWith)`

So eventually it should look something like this:

```
// "Hello thereworld".replace('world', 'new');
mainstring = mainstring.replace('world', 'new');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q6r899bx/2/

Now you can only search and replace `world` but as you said, the part after `there` is variable. So my best guess is to replace everything after `there` with a new word.

You can still use `indexOf` for that:

```
var index = mainstring.indexOf(substring);

// begin at first character, untill the start+length of substring
mainstring = mainstring.substr(0, index + substring.length);

// now: mainstring = 'Hello there'

mainstring += task;

// now: mainstring = 'Hello therenew'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6r899bx/4/